# Recording video by using Python

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, video-capture

```
import cv
cv.NamedWindow("camera",1)
cap = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
cv.SetCaptureProperty(cap,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT,200)
out = cv.CreateVideoWriter('output.avi',cv.CV_FOURCC('X','V','I','D'),20,(640,480))
while True:
    img = cv.QueryFrame(cap)
    cv.WriteFrame(out,img)
    cv.ShowImage("camera",img)
    if cv.WaitKey(10) == 27:
        break
cv.DestroyAllWindows()
```

Here is my code. In my opinion, a 10 seconds video file which named `output.avi` will be saved by running this code. However, nothing was saved in the end. Also, the window 'camera' did not closed as well.

Answer (score 0):

go for this ffmpeg. There is a python wrapper.

http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/